# How can i change the 'Edit in SharePoint Designer' menu item under the 'Site Actions' menu to open the pages in SPD 2010 instead of SPD 2007?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have both SPD 2007 and SPD 2010 installed on my machine. When i open a SharePoint 2010 site in IE and try to click on the 'Edit in SharePoint Designer' menu item under the 'Site Actions' menu. It tries to open the page in SPD 2007, not in SPD 2010.

How can i change the link to open the pages in SPD 2010 instead of SPD 2007 ?

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the internet explorer and system level settings instead of settings related to SharePoint.

In IE, go to Tools > Internet Options > Programs and see if "Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2010" is selected as the "HTML Editor".

Othewrwise go to set default programs from the control panel and set SPD 2010 as the default HTML Editor.

Try this out and let us know if this works.

Comment: In IE it shows "Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer" under HTML Editor. And under 'Set default programs' i can not see "SharePoint Designer 2010".

Comment: Same problem as Amit has here..